# Getting many NullReferenceException from PlayServicesResolver after adding Firebase Crashlytics to my project

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am currently migrating my Unity app from Fabric to Firebase following this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migrate-from-fabric.

After importing the **FirebaseCrashlytics.unitypackage** into my project, the PlayServicesResolver starts to throw the following NullReferenceException:

```
GooglePlayServices.AndroidAbis.get_Current () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.VWWf5QhVMz/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/AndroidAbis.cs:243)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+PropertyPoller`1[GooglePlayServices.AndroidAbis].Poll (System.Func`1 getCurrentValue, GooglePlayServices.Changed changed) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.VWWf5QhVMz/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:278)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.PollAndroidAbis () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.VWWf5QhVMz/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1139)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:127)
```

My current Unity Version is 2017.4.10f1 using .NET version 3.5. I am trying to import Firebase SDK version 5.6.1.

Has anyone else experienced this crash? Any idea what might be happening?

When I try going to an older version of the Firebase SDK, the issue seems to go away; however I would like to get my project set up in such a way that it can work with newer versions of Firebase as they come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Try the latest version of Play Services Resolver for Unity from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver).

2- Update your Android SDK tools from the SDK Manager to the latest version. I think it needs the last Android SDK Build-tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Updating my project from the Play Services Resolver v1.2.103 to v1.2.104 fixed the issue.